# Основа фильтрации вывода данных из MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, фильтрация

Уважаемые знатоки!

Нужно организовать расширенную фильтрацию вывода данных из MySQL. Мне интересно с чего начать, что нужно знать и как правильно разработать, чтобы в дальнейшем можно было без проблем добавлять другие параметры фильтрации и соответственно не нагружать базу данных.

На картинке, что я прикрепил ниже, видно тип фильтрации, как я хочу сделать.

Пожалуйста, подскажите мне, имеются ли специальные фреймворки, или объясните алгоритм PHP для разработки фильтрации данных.

Спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а в чём именно вопрос? как динамически запрос формировать с `where`?

Comment: @pavel, Вопрос в следующем: с чего мне начать, объясните алгоритм фильтрации данных, ибо я не знаю ничего о фильтрации.

Comment: да какой там алгоритм. Тупо вбивайте SQL - запрос. типо `Select .... where ... = ... and ... = ...` параметры думаю подставить несложно.

Comment: @pavel, как, например, вывести все доступные параметры для фильтрации? как это все организовать. Мне достаточно алгоритма на языке PHP. БД Mysql.

Comment: Никакого алгоритма не нужно, просто сделай форму на HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала нужно определиться со схемой хранения данных.

Вам нужны следующие таблицы:

1. Свойства (property) — в ней хранятся категории для фильтрации (id, property_name)
2. Значения свойств (property_value) — в таблице хранятся значения свойств (id, value, property_id)
3. Таблица с товарами — в таблице хранятся товары с привязкой к таблице property_2_product
4. Таблица property_2_product — в таблице хранится привязка свойства к товарам (id, product_id, property_value_id)

Для построения фильтра Вам нужно выбрать значения из первых двух таблиц.
Для вывода результатов Вам необходимо выбрать данные из 3 и 4 таблицы с учётом фильтрации.

Алгоритм PHP простой.

Для вывода фильтра:

1. Выбираем категории фильтров и значения для фильтрации
2. В цикле выводим данные

Для фильтрации товаров:

1. Фильтр представляет собой HTML форму — результаты попадают в PHP.
2. В PHP получаем параметры фильтрации.
3. Выбираем товары по параметрам из таблицы товаров

Comment: Открыли глаза! Теперь понимаю в какую сторону двигаться. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Есть два пути,

1 - Написать "комбайн с вертикальным взлетом", который будет парсить XML конфиг с абстрактным описанием всевозможных фильтров

Плюсы:

- Простота добавления новых фильтров.

Минусы:

- Несоразмерная задаче сложность разработки и развития
- Просадка производительности
- Сложность поиска точки отказа
- Возникшее через два года понимание, что нужно добавить фильтр, который не ложится в схему. Костыли, попаболь и прочие радости жизни
- Возникшее через три года понимание, что за все эти три года был добавлен всего один фильтр, да и тот из предыдущего пункта

2 - Не заниматься ерундой и захардкодить нужные на текущий момент фильтры (соблюдая правила хорошего кода ессно)

Плюсы:

- Простота разработки и развития
- Таки скорость работы
- Простота поиска точки отказа

Минусы:

- Ну да, для добавления нового фильтра потребуется доработка